# how to find special characters in a field of a table

Tags: sql

Please suggest how to find special characters in a field of a table.
I have tried query :

```
Select * form emp where ename like '%?%%';
```

but no row is getting selected .

Comment: Which database you are using

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: If "special characters" mean the LIKE wildcards `_` and `%` there's an ESCAPE in Standard SQL: `ename like '%?\%%' ESCAPE '\';` searches for the combination  `?%` within the string. For this simple case it's the same as `POSITION('?%' IN ename) > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Sql Server`, You can use `[^]` wildcard in `like` operator.

> Any single character not within the specified range

Use this query to find anything apart from `a-z` and `0-9`

```
SELECT ename
FROM emp
WHERE ename like '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
```